# Windows Service Not Starting Automatically After Reboot (Startup Type is Automatic)

Tags: windows, service, windows-server-2012-r2

we have a custom windows service which runs on a user account. Whenever we reboot the server, the service stops. To start the service again, we have to enter the password again in the service' **Log On** tab. What is causing this and how to resolve the issue?

Comment: I'v voting to close this question as it does not appear programming related. ServerFault would be a better fit and _possibly_ with more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior you describe can occur when service user is in a domain and the domain policy periodically overwrites the local policy, dropping the "Log on as a service" right for that user.

To fix the problem, edit your domain group policy (with [gpmc.msc](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754347.aspx)) and ensure that the service's user has the "Log on as a service" right.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft Windows Service Control Manager controls the state (i.e., started, stopped, paused, etc.) of all installed Windows services. By default, the Service Control Manager will wait 30,000 milliseconds (30 seconds) for a service to respond. Certain configurations, technical restrictions, or performance issues may result in the service taking longer than 30 seconds to start and report ready to the Service Control Manager.

By editing or creating the ServicesPipeTimeout DWORD value, the Service Control Manager timeout period can be overridden, thereby giving the service more time to start up and report ready to the service.

**How to make it ?**

1. Go to Start > Run > and type regedit
2. Navigate to: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control
3. With the control folder selected, right click in the pane on the right and select new DWORD Value
4. Name the new DWORD: ServicesPipeTimeout
5. Right-click ServicesPipeTimeout, and then click Modify
6. Click Decimal, type '180000', and then click OK
7. Restart the computer

**Note:** The recommendation above increases the timeout to 180,000 milliseconds (3 minutes), but this may need to be increased further depending on your environment. Keep in mind that increasing this value will likely yield longer server boot times.